# Is there any way to search in json postgres column using matching clause?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to search for a record from the Postgres JSON column. The stored data has a structure is like this

```
{
  "contract_shipment_date": "2015-06-25T19:00:00.000Z",
  "contract_product_grid": [
    {
      "product_name": "Axele",
      "quantity": 22.58
    },
    {
      "product_name": "Bell",
      "quantity": 52.58
    }
  ],
  "lc_status": "Awaited" 
}
```

My table name is Heap and column name is contract_product_grid. Also, contract_product_grid column can contain multiple product records.
I found this documentation but not able to get the desired output.

The required case is, I have a filter in which users can select product_name and on the basics of entered name by using matching clause, the record will be fetched and returned to users.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, it is quite clear. Also have a look at this example, is very similar to your problem: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

Comment: Do you want an exact match (using `=`)  or a wildcard match (using `LIKE`)

Comment: Using wildcards (Like, In etc)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you entered `Axele` as a `product_name` input, and want to return the matching value for `quantity` key.

Then use :

```
SELECT js2->'quantity' AS quantity
  FROM
  (
   SELECT JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(value::json) AS js2
     FROM heap,
     JSON_EACH_TEXT(contract_product_grid) AS js
    WHERE key = 'contract_product_grid' 
  ) q
  WHERE js2->> 'product_name' = 'Axele'
```

where expand the outermost JSON into `key`&`value` pairs through `JSON_EACH_TEXT(json)`, and split all the elements with the newly formed array by `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(value::json)` function.

Then, filter out by spesific `product_name` within the main query.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5e07e47db4af6cce1931417315c51016)</kbd>

*P.S. Don't forget to wrap JSON column's value up with curly braces*

Comment: Thanks for this, but it gives following error: ERROR:  cannot deconstruct an array as an object

Comment: what's your DBMS version @MuhammadIsrarShahid ? Have you looked at the demo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the array in order to be able to use a LIKE condition on each value:

```
select h.*
from heap h
where exists (select * 
              from jsonb_array_elements(h.contract_product_grid -> 'contract_product_grid') as p(prod)
              where p.prod ->> 'product_name' like 'Axe%')
```

If you don't really need a wildcard search (so `=` instead of `LIKE`) you can use the contains operator `@>` which is a lot more efficient:

```
select h.*
from heap h
where h.contract_product_grid -> 'contract_product_grid' @> '[{"product_name": "Axele"}]';
```

This can also be used to search for multiple products:

```
select h.*
from heap h
where h.contract_product_grid -> 'contract_product_grid' @> '[{"product_name": "Axele"}, {"product_name": "Bell"}]';
```

---

If you are using Postgres **12** you can simplify that a bit using a [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression:

```
select *
from heap
where jsonb_path_exists(contract_product_grid, '$.contract_product_grid[*].product_name ? (@ starts with "Axe")')
```

Or using a regular expression:

```
select *
from heap
where jsonb_path_exists(contract_product_grid, '$.contract_product_grid[*].product_name ? (@ like_regex "axe.*" flag "i")')
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(contract_product_grid::json) AS js2
     FROM heaps
    WHERE 'contract_product_grid' = 'contract_product_grid' 
  ) q
  WHERE js2->> 'product_name' IN ('Axele', 'Bell')` 

As, I mentioned in question that my column name is 'contract_product_grid' and i have to only search from it.
Using this query, I'm able to get contract_product_grid information using IN clause with entered product name.

Comment: But that doesn't use a wildcard. If you don't need a wildcard search using the `@>` operator would be way more efficient.